# Code works fine in PHP 5.4.3 but not int 5.3.8

Tags: php

I have the following line of code that is throwing an error when used in PHP 5.3.1 and 5.3.8 and I presume all of 5.3.x. Only noticed it when I uploaded it to a server as it works fine on my local PHP 5.4.3

```
if (isset($args[0]['field_date']['und'][0]['value']['date'])) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

The error that is coming up is

> Cannot use string offset as an array in my_module.module line 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you initializing `$args`? You can't use it as a string prior to performing array functions on it.

http://informationideas.com/news/2006/06/14/fatal-error-cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in/

Comment: $args is an array, not a string

Comment: Somewhere down the line, what should be an array is a string. Perhaps `$args[0]` is a string, or `$args[0]['field_date']` is a string, or `$args[0]['field_date']['und']`, etc...